# Qual a diferença entre KnockoutJS e AngularJS/EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mvvm, knockoutjs

Qual a diferença entre [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com/) e [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)/[EmberJS](http://emberjs.com/)? Pelo que eu andei pesquisando:

- Aparentemente o KnockoutJS tem uma curva de aprendizado bem menor, pode ser integrado a sites estáticos já existentes e tem melhor compatibilidade, mas é menos poderoso.
- Enquanto Angular/Ember são mais difíceis de trabalhar, precisando começar o site do zero com eles e podem ter problemas de incompatibilidade com *browsers mobile*, mas são bem mais poderosos.

Essas minhas suposições estão corretas?

Pergunto porque com [tantas opções](http://todomvc.com/) fica difícil decidir qual aprender. Minha única experiência com este tipo de *framework* é com [este tutorial interativo aqui](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/).

Comment: o site codeschool.com está com um ótico curso, patrocinado pelo google, de AngularJs. O curso é bem didático e passa por quase todas as funcionalidades. E tem uma ótima música de tema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## KnockOut

Como o próprio site do KnockoutJs diz, ele é uma biblioteca. Um conjunto de funções que visa facilitar o bind entre o DOM e o ViewModel em javascript.

> Knockout is a **JavaScript library** that helps you to create rich, responsive display and editor user interfaces with a clean underlying data model.

*Fonte: [http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html_)*

Por ser apenas uma biblioteca, não requer que o projeto todo seja modelado para o seu padrão. Basta adicionar os bindings a uma página, nova ou já existente, vincular ao viewModel e já está funcionando.

Tem diversas funcionalidades muito interessantes como bindings de atributos e eventos de elementos do DOM, e a utilização de custom bindings.

### Definição de biblioteca

> Uma biblioteca é um conjunto de dados e código fonte, utilizado no desenvolvimento de softwares. É desenhada para auxiliar o desenvolvedor e o compilador a construir e executar o software.

*Fonte: [http://www.techopedia.com/definition/3828/software-library](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/3828/software-library_)*

## AngularJs/EmberJs

Já o EmberJs/AngularJs/BackBoneJs são frameworks que por definição englobam muito mais funcionalidades que uma biblioteca.

Título so site do AngularJS

> AngularJS — Superheroic JavaScript **MVW Framework**

### Definição de framework

> Framework é um conjunto de classes que colaboram para realizar uma
>   responsabilidade para um domínio de um subsistema da aplicação.   ”
>   *Fayad e Schmidt*

Comment: Me desculpe por não ter sido muito claro. Editei minha pergunta para expressar melhor o que eu quero.

Comment: @Andrey, esta mudança foi consideravelmente drástica. Vou remover a resposta, mas recomendo a você ler http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1682/o-que-fazer-quando-o-o-p-muda-sua-pergunta?cb=1 pois não é desejável transformar uma pergunta em outra, e sim uma nova pergunta. A edição é com o objetivo de deixá-la mais clara e corrigir possiveis erros.

Comment: OK, o erro foi meu em me expressar mal quando fiz a pergunta, mas vou seguir sua recomendação e deixar assim.

Comment: @Andrey para sua nova pergunta: http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/04/12/comparison-angular-backbone-can-ember/